# Problems with x_sendfile in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, x-sendfile

I’m having some problems with John Guenin's x_sendfile (http://john.guen.in/past/2007/4/17/send_files_faster_with_xsendfile/).

When coding the download of a PDF file, I’m using the following code:

```
def send_the_file(filename)
  xsendfile (“#{Rails.root}/doc/” + filename, :type => ‘application/pdf’)
end
```

but I only get 1 byte downloaded. This usually happens if the filename is not absolute (hence the #{Rails.root} being added. I’ve also checked that the file has the necessary permissions. This is failing both on localhost and my prod site.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

TIA,

Urf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Rails are you using? If you're on 2.1 or later, the X-Sendfile option is built into Rails' send_file method.

```
send_file 'filename', :x_sendfile => true
```

Otherwise, are you sure that mod_xsendfile has been installed and configured correctly?

Comment: I'm on 2.2.2 and had tried the send_file already. However you could well be right on the mod_sendfile. I asked for it to be set up on my prod server but forgot to install it on dev! Doh! :$ thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make sure that your are actually using a web server that supports xsendfile.  If you are dev mode you probably aren't and it may fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in apche httpd.conf file
XSendFileAllowAbove on